# Why does Fortify SCA flag some Java ternary conditions as Always false or Always true

Tags: java, fortify, ternary

I have been reviewing a lot of Fortify findings lately, and I am trying to understand why Fortify SCA is flagging some, not all, Java ternary conditions as either 'Always false' or 'Always true'.  Examples below.
Can anyone provide insight into this?  Thanks in advance.

These examples are all in Entity classes.

This is flagged as "Always false".

```
public void setGmtInd(String gmtInd) {
    this.gmtInd = gmtInd != null ? gmtInd.toUpperCase() : gmtInd;
}
```

This is flagged as "Always true".

```
public void setDefaultValueInd(String defaultValueInd) {
    this.defaultValueInd = defaultValueInd != null ? defaultValueInd.toUpperCase() : defaultValueInd;
}
```

This is NOT flagged as a finding.

```
public void setUserid(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid != null ? userid.toUpperCase() : userid;
}
```

Comment: Inspect all calls.

Comment: Thanks @JoopEggen Your comment made me go back and dig much deeper into this application.  Now it's time to correct some code.

Answer (score 0):

I dug deeper into the application code and found the following.
The ones flagged as Always false, are always being called with a null value.

```
this.setGmtInd(null);
```

The ones flagged as Always true, are always being called with a hardcoded value.

```
this.setDefaultValueInd("Y");
this.setDefaultValueInd("N");
```

The ones not being flagged are, of course, being used properly.

```
this.setUserid("");
this.setUserid(cmosUser.getUserid());
```

I apologize for wasting your time on this one...  Next time, I will dig much deeper first.